# How to mock class which within other class

Tags: phpunit, mockery

#### Connect.php

```
class Connect
{
    private $dbName;

    public function __construct($dbName)
    {
        $this->dbName = $dbName;
    }

    public function getQuery()
    {
        return $this->dbName;
    }
}
```

#### ConnectFacade.php

```
class ConnectFacade
{
    public $dbA;
    public $dbB;
    public $dbC;
    public $dbD;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbA = new Connect('connect to database a');
        $this->dbB = new Connect('connect to database b');
        $this->dbC = new Connect('connect to database c');
        $this->dbD = new Connect('connect to database d');
    }
}
```

#### Member.php

```
class Member
{
    private $connect;

    public function __construct(ConnectFacade $connect)
    {
        $this->connect = $connect;
    }

    public function data()
    {
        return $this->connect->dbA->getQuery();
    }
}
```

#### index.php

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

echo (new Member(new ConnectFacade))->data();
```

In my case, I have many tables from many databases need to be connected in one class, therefore I need to declare many connections with different connection name very often, so I put it to `ConnectFacade` for saving time, I know it's kind of complicated, but that's the structure of my company, this sample code will show `connect to database a` on index.php, of course in reality the connection is doing a lot of stuffs, my question is I don't know how mock on this situation, this is what I tried

```
use Mockery as m;

class MemberTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testData()
    {
        $connect = m::mock('ConnectFacade');
        $connect->shouldReceive('dbA->getQuery')
            ->once()
            ->andReturn(true);
        $actual = (new Member($connect))->data();
        $this->assertTrue($actual);
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        m::close();
    }
}
```

and I got `Call to a member function getQuery() on a non-object in D:\www\phpunit\class\Member.php on line 14`, I don't know how to make the test pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `dbA` is not a method on ConnectFacade, but rather a variable. Therefore `$connect->shouldReceive('dbA->getQuery')` won't work.

Instead you need to set the `dbA` variable as a mock and then change the expectation to just receive `getQuery`:

```
public function testData()
{
    $connect = m::mock('ConnectFacade');
    $connect->dbA = $connect;
    $connect->shouldReceive('getQuery')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(true);
    $actual = (new Member($connect))->data();
    $this->assertTrue($actual);
}
```

Another option would be to instead mock the creation of the Connect class in ConnectFacade instead of mocking the whole ConnectFacade:

```
public function testData()
{
    $connect = m::mock('overload:Connect');
    $connect->shouldReceive('getQuery')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(true);
    $connectFacade = new ConnectFacade;
    $actual = (new Member($connectFacade))->data();
    $this->assertTrue($actual);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, really helpful, may I ask why $connect->dbA = $connect works, I mean I know it's a variable, but why equals to $connect

Comment: And the second method failed

`1) MemberTest::testData
Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method getQuery() from Connect should b                                                                                                                                                             e called
 exactly 1 times but called 0 times.`

Comment: For the first question `$connect->dbA = $connect` works because then you set the Mockery object as this variable. Then when you run `$this->connect->dbA->getQuery();` in the data()-method it will call the `getQuery` expectation on this Mockery object and return true.

For your second question I don't know why it fails. I tried to copy your code and when I run the tests it passes. Maybe there is some issue with the namespace when you define the mock? Maybe it should be something like `$connect = m::mock('overload:YourNamespace\Connect');`?

Comment: Nope, I autoload those class by classmap, it's just not work, but first solution is fine, thanks